# How to solve the diffiusion eqauation when $D$ is not constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the diffusion equation when $D=D(x,t)\;?$

I have to solve this differential equation with $x\in[0,a]$:

$\dfrac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D(x,t)\dfrac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)
=\dfrac{\partial D(x,t)}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x}+D(x,t)\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$

IC: $\phi(x,0)=\phi_0$.

BC1: $D(x,t)\dfrac{\partial \phi(x,t)}{\partial x}=M_A\cdot \phi(x,t)$, for $x=a$, where $M_A$ is a constant.

BC2: $|\phi(0,t)|<\infty$.

I can solve this equation if I solve this other equation:

$$a_2(x)y''+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y=0$$
where $a_i(x)>0$.

Comment: This is probably a really hard, if not totally insoluble question. (For example, if you let $D$ be imaginary, then I think this is equivalent to asking for a general solution to the Schrodinger equation.)

Comment: There is not an approximation or a solution of a particular case in the literature?

Comment: There are probably lots of approximation methods, but as it stands this question is about as broad as asking "how do I solve the Schrodinger equation?"

Comment: @knzhou Easy, $$|\psi(t)\rangle=\mathcal{T}\exp\left[ -\mathrm{i}\int^t_0 H(t')\,\mathrm{d}t' \right]|\psi(0)\rangle!$$

Comment: Would it be fine to do it numerically? As knzhou said, you have to approach it knowing some approximation schemes. Do you have any boundary conditions? Any physical constraints? Otherwise, as it stands, it would be very hard to start with an Ansatz.

Comment: Well actually there some boundary conditions, I'll add them to the question, and may I ask if I can change $D$ with its linear aproximation?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for your math question?

Comment: I briefly touch on the numerics in [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/137707/25301) (and  [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/150038/25301) may also help).

Comment: @0celo7 I didn't understand you coment

Comment: @GuadalupeAnimation It was directed at knzhou, don't worry about it.